# When does the isomorphism $G/H_1/H_2\simeq G/(H_1\times H_2)$ hold?

Tags: lie-groups, quotient-spaces, quotient-group

In the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3000710/real-grassmann-manifold-and-orthonormal-groups) it seems that
$$
\frac{O(n)/O(n-k)}{O(k)}\simeq \frac{O(n)}{O(n-k)\times O(k)}
$$
should be obvious. How can I see this?
Does this relation hold for $O(N)$ only or for more general Lie groups and subgroups too?

Comment: Quotients as what? These are not normal subgroups. If they were normal, then the answer would be "yes", whenever you have a pair of normal subgroups forming a direct product like that.

Comment: About grassmannians, see as well https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3240066.